# I am stuck on haskell input

Tags: haskell, input, io

I'm new to haskell and I have an assignment that involves parsing a string into a tree and doing some junk with it.
I've just about finished (everything is functionally fine right now) but as I've gone through the development, I've been using a static string definition as opposed to entering the input each time.

Here is an example input.
ex1 = "C1,8R1+4;R3-4C2C7+4;R5R2-3C1-6+3;R2-3C6+2;"

The last thing I need to do is handle user input (the input should come from standard in, not some definition).
Not only do I not know how to get input for sure, but I'm beginning to think I'm royally screwed because of the nature of haskell. I mean, it seems like the entire language is just nested statements within nested statements with recursive nested statements and so on and so forth. It's a confusing mess to me. I'm not even sure what to ask... so far my attempts at getting user input have meant that I need to start throwing around the input as a parameter to every single function in the entire program just to get it to compile.
Is there any way I can turn user input into a definition like the above? Or perhaps even just cheat with a global string variable? I'm desperate :( Thanks.

I know it's probably bad to be posting my entire program but I feel like I need to so I can show how intertwined it all is, making it difficult to figure out how to proceed.

It is the function createNodeContentList (near the bottom) that actually uses the definition of ex1.

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Data.List.Split

ex1 = "C1,8R1+4;R3-4C2C7+4;R5R2-3C1-6+3;R2-3C6+2;"

treePat = "(([RC][0-9]*[,-]?[0-9]*)*[+][0-9]*;)"
rangePat = "([RC][0-9]*[-][0-9]*)"
nodePat = "([RC][0-9,-]*)"

breakIntoInputTrees x = endBy ";" x
breakIntoInputNodes x = getAllTextMatches $ x =~ nodePat :: [String]

data NodeContent = NodeContent { idy::Char, vals::[Int] } deriving (Show)
data Tree = Node { content::NodeContent, children::[Tree]} deriving (Show)
data GridMod = GridMod { rows::[Int], cols::[Int], mod::[Int] } deriving (Show)
data Path = Path { pathSum::Int, corner::[Char] } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

go = printCornerNames $ maxOfMinPaths (maxOfMinValues 0 listOfMinPaths) listOfMinPaths

printCornerNames pathList = putStrLn $ unwords [ corner path | path <- pathList ]

maxOfMinPaths max [] = []
maxOfMinPaths max (h:t) = if (pathSum h == max) 
                            then h:maxOfMinPaths max t
                            else maxOfMinPaths max t

maxOfMinValues max [] = max
maxOfMinValues max (h:t) = if (pathSum h > max) 
                            then maxOfMinValues (pathSum h) t 
                            else maxOfMinValues max t 

listOfMinPaths = findMinimums finalArray

findMinimums array = [quadMinPath array center 0 rMod cMod | rMod <- [-1,1], cMod <- [-1,1]] 

quadMinPath array (r,c) sum rMod cMod
    | isCorner (r,c)    = Path (sum + (posVal array r c)) (cornerName (r,c))
    | otherwise         = decidePaths array (r,c) sum rMod cMod

decidePaths array (r,c) sum rMod cMod
    | (validRow (r + rMod) && validCol (c + cMod)) =
        minimum     [   
                        quadMinPath array (r + rMod, c) (sum + (posVal array r c)) rMod cMod,
                        quadMinPath array (r, c + cMod) (sum + (posVal array r c)) rMod cMod
                    ]
    | (validRow (r + rMod)) = quadMinPath array (r + rMod, c) (sum + (posVal array r c)) rMod cMod
    | otherwise = quadMinPath array (r, c + cMod) (sum + (posVal array r c)) rMod cMod

posVal array r c = array !! (toIndex r c)

isCorner x = elem x [(1,1), (1,cMax), (rMax,1), (rMax,cMax)]

cornerName x    | x == (1,1) = "TOP-LEFT" | x == (1,cMax) = "TOP-RIGHT" 
                | x == (rMax,1) = "BOTTOM-LEFT" | x == (rMax,cMax) = "BOTTOM-RIGHT"

validRow r = if (r >= 1 && r <= rMax) then True else False
validCol c = if (c >= 1 && c <= cMax) then True else False

rMax = fst findMaximums
cMax = snd findMaximums

center = (quot (fst findMaximums) 2 + 1, quot (snd findMaximums) 2 + 1)

finalArray = modifyArray (createArray findMaximums) (toModifiers createGridModders)

modifyArray array [] = array
modifyArray array ((r,c,m):t) = modifyArray (addToArray array (toIndex r c) m) t

addToArray array index mod = (take index array) ++ [(mod + array !! index)] ++ (drop (index + 1) array)

toIndex r c = (r - 1) * (snd findMaximums) + c - 1

createArray (maxR,maxC) = (take (maxR * maxC)) (repeat 0)

printArray array =  mapM_ putStrLn [ printRow row | row <- (chunksOf (snd findMaximums) array)]
printRow row = unwords (map show row)

toModifiers gridModders = flat [ toModifier gw | gw <- gridModders ]

toModifier (GridMod r c m) = [ (x,y,head m) | x <- r, y <- c]

createGridModders = adjustForMaximums (treeWalk (GridMod [] [] []) buildAllTrees)

adjustForMaximums gridMods = [ fillMax gm findMaximums | gm <- gridMods ] 

fillMax (GridMod [] [] m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod [1..maxR] [1..maxC] m)
fillMax (GridMod [] c m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod [1..maxR] c m)
fillMax (GridMod r [] m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod r [1..maxC] m)
fillMax (GridMod r c m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod r c m)

treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) []) = [(GridMod v c m)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) []) = [(GridMod r v m)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'M' v) []) = [(GridMod r c v)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod v c m) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r v m) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'M' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r c v) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'Z' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r c m) tree) | tree <- ch ]

flat [] = []
flat (h:t) = h ++ flat t

findMaximums = (oddify(findMaxRows buildAllTrees), oddify(findMaxCols buildAllTrees))

oddify num = num + ((Prelude.mod num 2) - 1) * (-1)

findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) []) = maximum v
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent _ _) []) = 0
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) c) = maximum (v ++ [ findMaxRows x | x <- c ])
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent _ _) c) = maximum [ findMaxRows x | x <- c ]

findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) []) = maximum v
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent _ _) []) = 0
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) c) = maximum (v ++ [ findMaxCols x | x <- c ])
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent _ _) c) = maximum [ findMaxCols x | x <- c ]

buildAllTrees = Node (NodeContent 'Z' []) (buildIntoTrees (createNodeContentList))

buildIntoTrees x = [ buildIntoTree treeNodeContentList | treeNodeContentList <- x ]

buildIntoTree (h:t) = Node h [ buildSubTree subList | subList <- (easyList t) ]

buildSubTree (h:t) = Node h [ Node content [] | content <- t ]

easyList nodeContentList = tail (simplifyNodeList (idy (head nodeContentList)) nodeContentList [] [])

simplifyNodeList identity [] fullList nextList = fullList ++ [nextList]
simplifyNodeList identity (h:t) fullList nextList = if (idy h == identity)
                                                        then simplifyNodeList identity t (fullList ++ [nextList]) [h]
                                                        else simplifyNodeList identity t fullList (nextList ++ [h])

createNodeContentList = [ tupleTreeToNodeContentList tupleTree | tupleTree <- (parseToListOfTupleTrees ex1)]

parseToListOfTupleTrees input = [ toTupleTree x | x <- breakIntoInputTrees input]

toTupleTree x = ('M', [modifier x]):[ createTupleNode y | y <- breakIntoInputNodes x]

modifier x = read (last (splitOn "+" x )) :: Int

createTupleNode nodeStr = (head nodeStr, getNodeNumbers nodeStr)

getNodeNumbers nodeStr = if (nodeStr =~ rangePat :: Bool)
                    then extractRange (onlyNumbers nodeStr)
                    else onlyNumbers nodeStr

onlyNumbers str = toInt (words (replaceNonDigit str))

extractRange numList = [head numList .. last numList]

replaceNonDigit [] = []
replaceNonDigit ('R':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit ('C':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit ('-':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit (',':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit (h:t) = h:replaceNonDigit t

toInt :: [String] -> [Int]
toInt = map read

tupleTreeToNodeContentList x = [ tupleNodeToNodeContent tupleNode | tupleNode <- x ]

tupleNodeToNodeContent x = NodeContent (fst x) (snd x)
```

Comment: For starter, you should edit your post with some (maybe simplified) code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Are you telling us that you parsing that string in one go? Surely, you have some top level function where you use `ex1` and pass it or parts of it to other functions? Just show us this one.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use a tiny toy example to get the idea across.

### Is `ex1` referenced a lot in your code? Use a parameter instead.

If your code is littered with references to `ex1`, there's a bit more work to do. For example, if you have

```
ex1 = "some sample input"
theWords = words ex1
wordLengths = [length word| word <- thewords]
```

then you need to add an additional parameter to each function so you can use it with any input, not just `ex1`:

```
ex1 = "some sample input"
getWords input = words input
wordLengths thewords = [length word | word <- thewords]
```

You may find that doing this simplifies code somewhat:

```
getWordLengths input = [length word | word <- words input]
```

### How to usefully use user input with your functions

Let's assume you've made a function that operates on user input, so a function of type `String -> SomethingOrOther`. Here's an example of how you could make that interacts with the user:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Please enter your thingumybob"
   input <- getLine
   putStrLn "Your answer is"
   print (getWordLengths input)
```

That's a rather brief example, but hopefully should be able to get you started at least.

### Read more

For more help on this topic, read the [Input and Output Chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) of [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Comment: I guess the problem is not that many functions rely specifically on the input, but rather I have like 50 functions which rely on the output of the function which uses the input. I tried to start throwing around the user input as a parameter to functions to fix my issue but with 160 lines of messy code and like 50 functions it just gets out of control and no matter how hard I try I can't even get it to compile when I try to do so. I wish there was just some way to turn user input into a global variable or something - even if that breaks the purity of haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Next time, remember, when you have something like

> I have an assignment that involves parsing a string into a tree

then your immediate start is to write:

```
assignment :: String -> Tree
```

You can start out with a function that maps any string to the empty tree:

```
assignment input = empty   -- or whatever produces an empty tree
```

And you're ready for the first test run with:

```
main = interact (show . assignment)
```

Now, all you need to do is to refine your `assignment` function!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.
I fixed my program (above) by changing the structure to be slightly more modular.
Before, it was basically just a chain of functions calling functions calling functions and so on. I've changed it so that different portions of the code are responsible for creating different steps of the solution, which are then used as parameters to the next portion.
Ultimately, the program is the same, just broken up more.

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Data.List.Split

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter the string representation of a tree:"
    input <- getLine
    let nodeContentList = createNodeContentList input
    let finalTree = buildAllTrees nodeContentList
    let maximums = findMaximums finalTree
    let gridModders = createGridModders finalTree maximums
    let finalArray = buildArray gridModders maximums
    let listOfPaths = findListOfMinPaths finalArray maximums
    showMaxOfMins listOfPaths

treePat = "(([RC][0-9]*[,-]?[0-9]*)*[+][0-9]*;)"
rangePat = "([RC][0-9]*[-][0-9]*)"
nodePat = "([RC][0-9,-]*)"

breakIntoInputTrees x = endBy ";" x
breakIntoInputNodes x = getAllTextMatches $ x =~ nodePat :: [String]

data NodeContent = NodeContent { idy::Char, vals::[Int] } deriving (Show)
data Tree = Node { content::NodeContent, children::[Tree]} deriving (Show)
data GridMod = GridMod { rows::[Int], cols::[Int], mod::[Int] } deriving (Show)
data Path = Path { pathSum::Int, corner::[Char] } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

showMaxOfMins listOfPaths = printCornerNames $ maxOfMinPaths (maxOfMinValues 0 listOfPaths) listOfPaths

printCornerNames pathList = putStrLn $ unwords [ corner path | path <- pathList ]

maxOfMinPaths max [] = []
maxOfMinPaths max (h:t) = if (pathSum h == max) 
                            then h:maxOfMinPaths max t
                            else maxOfMinPaths max t

maxOfMinValues max [] = max
maxOfMinValues max (h:t) = if (pathSum h > max) 
                            then maxOfMinValues (pathSum h) t 
                            else maxOfMinValues max t 

findListOfMinPaths array maximums = findMinimums array maximums

findMinimums array maximums = [quadMinPath array (center maximums) 0 rMod cMod maximums | rMod <- [-1,1], cMod <- [-1,1]] 

quadMinPath array (r,c) sum rMod cMod maximums
    | isCorner (r,c) maximums   = Path (sum + (posVal array r c maximums)) (cornerName (r,c) maximums)
    | otherwise                 = decidePaths array (r,c) sum rMod cMod maximums

decidePaths array (r,c) sum rMod cMod maximums
    | (validRow (r + rMod) maximums && validCol (c + cMod) maximums) =
        minimum     [   
                        quadMinPath array (r + rMod, c) (sum + (posVal array r c maximums)) rMod cMod maximums,
                        quadMinPath array (r, c + cMod) (sum + (posVal array r c maximums)) rMod cMod maximums
                    ]
    | (validRow (r + rMod) maximums) = quadMinPath array (r + rMod, c) (sum + (posVal array r c maximums)) rMod cMod maximums
    | otherwise = quadMinPath array (r, c + cMod) (sum + (posVal array r c maximums)) rMod cMod maximums

posVal array r c maximums = array !! (toIndex r c maximums)

isCorner x maximums = elem x [(1,1), (1,cMax maximums), (rMax maximums,1), (rMax maximums,cMax maximums)]

cornerName x maximums   | x == (1,1) = "TOP-LEFT" | x == (1,cMax maximums) = "TOP-RIGHT" 
                        | x == (rMax maximums,1) = "BOTTOM-LEFT" | x == (rMax maximums,cMax maximums) = "BOTTOM-RIGHT"

validRow r maximums = if (r >= 1 && r <= (rMax maximums)) then True else False
validCol c maximums = if (c >= 1 && c <= (cMax maximums)) then True else False

rMax maximums = fst maximums
cMax maximums = snd maximums

center maximums = (quot (fst maximums) 2 + 1, quot (snd maximums) 2 + 1)

buildArray gridModders maximums = modifyArray (createArray maximums) (toModifiers gridModders) maximums

modifyArray array [] maximums = array
modifyArray array ((r,c,m):t) maximums = modifyArray (addToArray array (toIndex r c maximums) m) t maximums

addToArray array index mod = (take index array) ++ [(mod + array !! index)] ++ (drop (index + 1) array)

toIndex r c maximums = (r - 1) * (snd maximums) + c - 1

createArray (maxR,maxC) = (take (maxR * maxC)) (repeat 0)

toModifiers gridModders = flat [ toModifier gw | gw <- gridModders ]

toModifier (GridMod r c m) = [ (x,y,head m) | x <- r, y <- c]

createGridModders finalTree maximums = adjustForMaximums (treeWalk (GridMod [] [] []) finalTree) maximums

adjustForMaximums gridMods maximums = [ fillMax gm maximums | gm <- gridMods ] 

fillMax (GridMod [] [] m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod [1..maxR] [1..maxC] m)
fillMax (GridMod [] c m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod [1..maxR] c m)
fillMax (GridMod r [] m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod r [1..maxC] m)
fillMax (GridMod r c m) (maxR,maxC) = (GridMod r c m)

treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) []) = [(GridMod v c m)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) []) = [(GridMod r v m)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'M' v) []) = [(GridMod r c v)]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod v c m) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r v m) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'M' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r c v) tree) | tree <- ch ]
treeWalk (GridMod r c m) (Node (NodeContent 'Z' v) ch) =  flat [ (treeWalk (GridMod r c m) tree) | tree <- ch ]

flat [] = []
flat (h:t) = h ++ flat t

findMaximums finalTree = (oddify(findMaxRows finalTree), oddify(findMaxCols finalTree))

oddify num = num + ((Prelude.mod num 2) - 1) * (-1)

findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) []) = maximum v
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent _ _) []) = 0
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent 'R' v) c) = maximum (v ++ [ findMaxRows x | x <- c ])
findMaxRows (Node (NodeContent _ _) c) = maximum [ findMaxRows x | x <- c ]

findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) []) = maximum v
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent _ _) []) = 0
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent 'C' v) c) = maximum (v ++ [ findMaxCols x | x <- c ])
findMaxCols (Node (NodeContent _ _) c) = maximum [ findMaxCols x | x <- c ]

buildAllTrees nodeContentList = Node (NodeContent 'Z' []) (buildIntoTrees nodeContentList)

buildIntoTrees x = [ buildIntoTree treeNodeContentList | treeNodeContentList <- x ]

buildIntoTree (h:t) = Node h [ buildSubTree subList | subList <- (easyList t) ]

buildSubTree (h:t) = Node h [ Node content [] | content <- t ]

easyList nodeContentList = tail (simplifyNodeList (idy (head nodeContentList)) nodeContentList [] [])

simplifyNodeList identity [] fullList nextList = fullList ++ [nextList]
simplifyNodeList identity (h:t) fullList nextList = if (idy h == identity)
                                                        then simplifyNodeList identity t (fullList ++ [nextList]) [h]
                                                        else simplifyNodeList identity t fullList (nextList ++ [h])

createNodeContentList input = [ tupleTreeToNodeContentList tupleTree | tupleTree <- (parseToListOfTupleTrees input)]

parseToListOfTupleTrees input = [ toTupleTree x | x <- breakIntoInputTrees input]

toTupleTree x = ('M', [modifier x]):[ createTupleNode y | y <- breakIntoInputNodes x]

modifier x = read (last (splitOn "+" x )) :: Int

createTupleNode nodeStr = (head nodeStr, getNodeNumbers nodeStr)

getNodeNumbers nodeStr = if (nodeStr =~ rangePat :: Bool)
                    then extractRange (onlyNumbers nodeStr)
                    else onlyNumbers nodeStr

onlyNumbers str = toInt (words (replaceNonDigit str))

extractRange numList = [head numList .. last numList]

replaceNonDigit [] = []
replaceNonDigit ('R':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit ('C':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit ('-':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit (',':t) = ' ':replaceNonDigit t
replaceNonDigit (h:t) = h:replaceNonDigit t

toInt :: [String] -> [Int]
toInt = map read

tupleTreeToNodeContentList x = [ tupleNodeToNodeContent tupleNode | tupleNode <- x ]

tupleNodeToNodeContent x = NodeContent (fst x) (snd x)
```